# tsc --watch not updating files when outDir present in tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

I am trying to write a nodejs command line app with Typescript and I have the following tsconfig file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist"
},
"include": ["src/*.ts"]
}
```

When I use `tsc` everything works as expected (*.js files appear in the dist folder).

However, when I run `tsc -w`, the js files are created in the dist folder at first, but not updated when I change any of the ts files. Tsc seems to be seeing and compiling changes just fine, but fails to write the actual js files.

```
4:23:04 PM - File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...
4:23:04 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

When I omit the outDir parameter from the tsconfig everything works (js files are being updated when chaning ts files). This is not a desired solution since I want js output to be in dist folder instead of src.

It also works correctly when I skip using the tsconfig.json file and run it directly:

```
tsc -w --outDir dist src/app.ts
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Running on win10, tsc 2.6.2, node 7.9.0

Comment: Seems to work correctly in macOS High Sierra with those specific versions of `tsc` and node.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it under Mac too and indeed it works. So it is a windows issue.

Answer (score 4):

I think I have this figured out.

Typescript 2.6 came with new --watch implementation. When downgrading to 2.5.3 everything works fine.

So this seems to be an issue with the new --watch thingy that manifests under specific conditions (win10, using outDir in tsconfig).

Reported it as a bug in Typescript issue tracker - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20739

Answer (score 3):

For me this was fixed by disabling the option *'Use "safe write" (save changes to a temporary file first)'* in WebStorm:

[image: WebStorm settings]

When enabled, the IDE deletes and renames files, which seems to confuse `tsc --watch`.

(To see what it's doing, use `tsc --extendedDiagnostics --listEmittedFiles`. Extended logs [in Arnelism's GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20739).)

Answer (score 0):

Get to the latest nightly build:

```
npm install -g typescript@next
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was trying to run the webpack serve from WSL2. When I ran it from Powershell the live reload works just fine though. I wonder why that is...